# vim how to use rubycomplete with supertab

Tags: vim

I installed [vim-ruby](https://github.com/vim-ruby/vim-ruby) through pathogen. I think I should be able to use `rubycomplete`, which is included in the `vim-ruby`, after installing it, but I am not.

there is not any error, I just can't use it.

when i use `:scriptnames` to check loaded scripts, i can see some scripts from `vim-ruby`, such as:

```
~/.vim/bundle/vim-ruby/ftdetect/ruby.vim
```

but I can't find `rubycomplete`. I think it's not loaded, but I don't know why.

I am using the default vim7.3 on Mac OS X 10.8.3, and this is my `.vimrc`:

```
call pathogen#infect()
syntax on
set nocompatible
filetype plugin indent on


set number
set autoindent
set smartindent
set shiftwidth=4
set tabstop=4
set backspace=2
set title
set autoread
set ignorecase
set incsearch
set hlsearch
set smartcase
set smarttab
autocmd FileType python set tabstop=4|set shiftwidth=4|set expandtab
autocmd FileType ruby set tabstop=2|set sw=2
autocmd FileType html set tabstop=2|set sw=2
autocmd BufNewFile,BufRead *.html.erb set filetype=html
autocmd BufNewFile,BufRead *.css.scss set filetype=css
autocmd FileType haml set tabstop=4|set shiftwidth=4|set expandtab
autocmd FileType ruby,eruby let g:rubycomplete_buffer_loading = 1
autocmd FileType ruby,eruby let g:rubycomplete_classes_in_global = 1
autocmd FileType ruby,eruby let g:rubycomplete_rails = 1
```

how can I make my vim load `rubycomplete` properly? I really need this awesome feature!

***--update--***

1) when I want to use `rubycomplete`:

```
[].
```

I supposed it should show something like `each` and `each_index`, which are the default methods of Array, when I pressed tab(I am using `supertab`).
however, vim showed:

```
-- Keyword completion (^N^P) Pattern not found
```

2) my vim is the default one of mac OSX, but there is `ruby+` in the output of `vim --version | grep ruby`. Therefore, I think my vim supports ruby, which means I don't need to recompile my vim. Am I right?

3) the output of `:verbose set omnifunc` is

```
omnifunc=rubycomplete#Complete
  Last set from ~/.vim/bundle/vim-ruby/ftplugin/ruby.vim
```

Comment: Can you do a `vim --version | grep ruby` you should make sure that a `+ruby` shows up. If it doesn't it means that you need to recompile vim with ruby support. If vim is the default one that ships with mac osx it does not contain ruby support.

Comment: Omnicomplete scripts are usually loaded "on demand", that's what the `autoload` directory is for. `rubycomplete.vim` is not supposed to show up in `:scriptnames` but it is supposed to kick in when you do `<C-x><C-o>`. What is the output of `:verbose set omnifunc` when you are in a ruby buffer?

Comment: Your question is almost a textbook example of [the XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). If you had mentioned that you were using SuperTab and thus keyword completion instead of the default omni completion mappings you'd have received your answer 12 hours ago.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Supertab has defaulted to keyword completion. This is not omnicompeltion. To get supertab to use omnicompletion you need to either use `<C-x><C-o>` first or set supertab to default to using omnicompletion.

To get supertab to use omnicompletion by default you can add the following line to your vimrc.

```
let g:SuperTabDefaultCompletionType = "<c-x><c-o>"
```

if you want it only for ruby you could use the autocmd below.

```
autocmd FileType ruby let g:SuperTabDefaultCompletionType = "<c-x><c-o>"
```

Also you can set supertab to switch between omni completion and one other completion mode automatically by setting it to context mode. To set this up you can just change the above line to

```
autocmd FileType ruby let g:SuperTabDefaultCompletionType = "context"
```

If you are planning on doing this I would recommend looking at `:h supertab` when fully setting it up.

Comment: thank you. sadly, vim still showed `-- Keyword completion (^N^P) Pattern not found` after trying your configuration. using `<C-x><C-o>` doesn't work, either.

Comment: @Brian which version of supertab are you using? This should work in version 2.0. (You should be able to check the version by opening up `$VIM/plugin/supertab.vim` and looking at the Version line)

Comment: @Brian did you copy the line (with the autocmd) above I accidentally stuck python in the FileType command in stead of ruby can you check that?